# How to track domain and sub domain traffic in different GA4 account?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, tracking, google-analytics-4

I have a news website for ex. ABC.com and sub-domain x.ABC.com I want to track traffic in two different GA4, so I created two GA4 and Tagmanagers account.

Both main domain and sub domain have different global head and body tag.

Now the problem is sub-domain's GA4 is showing some main domain's news urls and their views and users. Not all news urls are showing in sub-domain's GA4 some random urls are showing, even in real time also.

And there is no direct-indirect link between domain and sub-domain. You have to manually type the url of sub domain if you want to go from main domain

I already cross check the GA4 measurement id and GTM code, all are good. and there is no direct

Answer (score 0):

The main domain's URLs must be coming as referrals into the sub-domain GA4 property. To avoid this you can use the "Referral Exclusion" option provided by GA4.
Go to your sub-domain GA4 property's Admin dashboard, Select Data Streams > Your data stream > Configure Tag Settings > List unwanted referrals > Add conditions
[image]
Select "Referral domain exactly matches" and add your main domain there in the input field. Save it. It might take 24 hours for data to populate.

To get analytics data from all the pages from the sub-domain try adding the "Initialization" trigger into your GA4 configuration tag in the GTM container linked to the sub-domain GA4 property. Add the "page hostname" condition there stating your sub-domain as the value in the input field.
[image]

This should resolve your problem.